# golang function returning value in incoming parameter

Tags: function, go

I'm a bit new to golang coming from a nodejs background.  I'm a bit confused as to why certain functions have a function signature in the following format

```
function readContents(var1 type, var2 *type)
```

If we consider the above function, `readContents`, reads contents into a pointer of `var2`.  Is this a standard practice in the go language where you pass parameters in and expect them to have return values.  A practical example is here https://github.com/vmihailenco/msgpack.  If you look at the quickstart it has the following code

```
err = msgpack.Unmarshal(b, &item)
```

I would normally expect it to return the value rather than modify the incoming value in `&item`.

Answer (score 1):

Return values are generally preferred.

The caller must specify the type of the target value to `msgpack.Unmarshal`.  The Unmarshal function can be restructured to use a return value like this:

```
  func Unmarshal(p []data, exampleValueOfType interface{}) (interface{}, error)
```

The calling code will look something like this:

```
v, err := msgpack.Unmarshal(b, (*X)(nil))
if err != nil {
       // handle error
}
x := v.(*X)
```

It's simpler for the caller to pass to pass a target value.  This avoids the type assertion and mentioning the type twice in the code:

```
var x X
if err := msgpack.Unmarshal(b, &x) {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm trying to understand a codebase using the second approach going through multiple layers and casting and its so confusing.